# How to Update table column in SQL SERVER DB based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following information:

```
ID         Value_N1        Date_N1     Value_N4      Date_N4
1           NULL          2017-05-31    0.236        2017-02-28
2           NULL          2017-05-31    0.589        2017-02-28
3           NULL          2017-08-30    0.898        2017-08-30
4           NULL          2017-11-30    0.789        2017-11-30
```

I want to update the **Value_N1** column with values from **Value_N4** where **Date_N1** is equal to **Date_N4**

I have tried to use the following query but am going nowhere with it:

```
Update TableName
set Value_N1 = (select Value_N4 from TbleName where Date_N1 = Date_N4)
```

Of-cause this query doesn't work because it returns more than one value. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic for setting the new value to `Value_N1` is on the right track, but the restrictions for which records to update should appear in a `WHERE` clause.

```
UPDATE TableName
SET Value_N1 = Value_N4
WHERE Date_N1 = Date_N4
```

Comment: Dude, this is very simple, didn't know!! Thanks for the insight!!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `CASE` expression.

**Query**

```
update TableName
set Value_N1 = (
    case when Date_N1 = Date_N4
    then Value_N4
    else Value_N1 end
);
```

Comment: this is also a valid contribution.. Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 1):

update TableName set Value_N1=Value_N4 where Date_N1=Date_N4